# Inserting data to a webserver by buttonclick

Tags: android, web-services

I have .net webservice and Its works properly through android but I am not able to insert data directly on the webserver via a click on a button.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    setContentView(textView);



    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
            OPERATION_NAME);




    request.addProperty("productName","payal");

    request.addProperty("Remark","remark");
    request.addProperty("Photo","photo");


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.bodyOut=request;
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

    try

    {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        Object response = envelope.getResponse();


        textView.setText(response.toString());

    }

    catch (Exception exception)

    {

        textView.setText(exception.toString());

    }

}


}
```

This code is working when hardcore value is there but How can i pass value through interface.

Comment: Am not getting what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("newValeur");
            pi.setValue(valeur);
            pi.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);
```